# How to GET sent json POST cURL in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, post, get

I'm trying to access data that has been sent from **sender.php** to **receiver.php** using post.

Here is my **sender.php**

```
<?php
 $param = array(
        'Name' => 'Mark',
        'Age' => '28'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example/receiver.php',
        CURLOPT_POST => 'TRUE',
        CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: '.strlen(json_encode($param))
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($param),
        )
    );

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);


?>
```

And here's my **receiver.php**. 
I need help on how I can display the data entered as result

```
<?php
echo json_decode(file_get_contents('https://example/sender.php'));
?>
```

Comment: _"here's my receiver.php"_ - So you're `receiver.php` calls itself? That would create an infinite loop.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry about that, I've corrected it

Comment: You've just added an extra step, but that would still cause an infinite loop. `sender.php` calls `receiver.php`, which calls `sender.php`, which calls `receiver.php` and so on... Try changing `file_get_contents('https://example...')` to `file_get_contents('php://input');`, which will give you the posted body.

Comment: `json_decode` returns an object or an array. Using echo makes not much sense here.